# Долго грузятся странички сайта

Tags: провайдер, веб-сервер, сервер, долгая-загрузка

Здравствуйте. Проблема заключается в следующем: сменил я недавно провайдера, настроил VPS и тут у меня стали очень долго грузиться странички и даже видео, css файлы, картинки по прямым ссылкам. Написал я в поддержку, мне ответили, что всё работает нормально, посоветовали оптимизировать БД и прочее, хотя я сомневаюсь, что видео по прямой ссылке открывается долго отнюдь не из-за не оптимизированной БД или апача. Но я заметил, что такое происходит в основном тогда, когда на сайте больше 15-20 пользователей. Канал забитым никогда не бывает, обычно используется ~9.5 Кб/с из 10.0 Мбит/с. Тормоза происходят не всегда, а периодически.

В чём проблема? Мой косяк или провайдера? на предыдущих серверах всё работало отлично.

**Обновление**

Кажется я начинаю понимать чём проблема... нормально ли, что апач потребляет столько памяти, да и вообще свободной памяти остаётся очень мало. В чём проблема? Скрин команды top http://rghost.ru/55876203/image.png

Answer (score 1):

есть предложение записывать, когда возникают тормоза. Если они сильнопериодические (например, каждые два часа), то возможно, это отрабатывает какой-то скрипт в cron'е. Например, он может делать backup. Или на этом сервере есть ещё другие пользователи, которые подгружают сервер.

есть хорошая команда uptime, которая показывает текущую нагрузку. И конечно же классический top для выяснения вредителя.